# 301 redirect for SEO purposes

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have to redirect from an old folder who doesn't exists anymore to a new one. I'll show you the configuration below:

Old: `**/examplefolder/index.html /examplefolder/example.html etc**`.
New: `**/example-folder/index.html /example-folder/example.html etc**`.

So basically if an user goes to /examplefolder/index.html it gets automatically redirected to `**/example-folder/index.html**`, and so on.

All I could come up with for the .htaccess file:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /examplefolder/(.*) /example-folder//$1
```

It doesn't look quite right to me. Can you please help?

Thanks

Comment: by htaccess or internal php code?

Comment: .htaccess, forgot to specify.

Answer (score 0):

use this code for .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond         /your/docroot/dir1/%{REQUEST_FILENAME}  -f
RewriteRule  ^(.+)  /your/docroot/dir1/$1  [L,R=301]
```

ref:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

Comment: Does that catch any file under the old folder and redirects the user to the new folder and same file?

Comment: for any file use:  ^(.*)$  insted of ^(.+)